# Postgres Trigger function performance issue

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

Postgres 9.3 x64 bit ,I am using a history table with user log.huge data insertion occurring on every second till now the data is is around 90 millions and still counting
I partitioned the table using date column for every month and I used a trigger where for each insert it will check weather for the particular month table is there or not, if there it will directly insert else it will try to create and insert the data. but the trigger taking soo much time to execute is there any way to improvise the performance

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION history_master_part_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE 
yr int;
mnth int;
tbname character varying;
sdate character varying;
edate character varying;
cnt int;
Begin
raise notice '%','something';
EXECUTE 'select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE '''||NEW.hm_date||''')' INTO yr;
EXECUTE 'select EXTRACT(month FROM DATE '''||NEW.hm_date||''')' INTO mnth;
tbname := 'history_master_part_y'||yr||'m'||mnth;
sdate :=yr||'-'||mnth||'-01';
IF mnth = 12 THEN
        edate :=yr+1||'-'||'01-01';
    ELSE 
edate :=yr||'-'||mnth+1||'-01';
END IF;
--raise notice 'table-----', tbname;
raise notice '%', sdate;
raise notice '%', edate;
raise notice '%',yr;
If(SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
  FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c
  JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
  WHERE  n.nspname = 'public'
  AND    c.relname = tbname
  AND    c.relkind = 'r'    -- only tables(?)
)) THEN
--INSERT INTO ||tbname|| VALUES ||NEW'.*)';
raise notice '%','inserting into'||tbname;
 EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO ' || tbname || ' SELECT ($1).*')
      USING NEW;
ELSE
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE '|| tbname||'(
CHECK ( hm_date >= DATE '''||sdate||''' AND hm_date < DATE '''||edate||''' )
) INHERITS (history_master_part)';
 EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO ' || tbname || ' SELECT  ($1).*')
      USING NEW;
 --RAISE EXCEPTION 'Caution Caution Caution Amit is getting angry';
END IF;
Return NULL;
End;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Comment: Don't try to create new tables within a trigger, it doesn't work with concurrency: Multiple clients try to create the same table at the same moment, most of them will fail. Create the partitions before you need them, it's faster and doesn't create new problems.

Comment: @FrankHeikens is there any other option to create the table on the go because I am trying to make it as one time process or else  I may need to create more than 36 partition for 3 years ,and I also need to create trigger for all

Comment: It's not a big deal to create 36 partitions ahead of time.  But I would write a crontab entry to just make them periodically.  I'd also write another cron job to run maybe once a week to check them so I'd get an error message if the create failed for some reason.

Comment: You might want to look into pg_partman: https://github.com/keithf4/pg_partman